# Is "medical" an extra word in this context?

Tags: redundancy

In this NYTimes headline:

"A father’s strategy of simply waiting out a medical malady proved successful."

I had a thought that being malady already in definition of disease OR sickness what is the purpose of using medical as its adjective??? aren't all disease or sickness medical?

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/malady) definition #1: ***a disease***. Definition #2 ***a problem within a system or organization.***

Answer (score 3):

While *malady* originally meant "A specific kind of illness; an ailment, a disease." (Oxford English Dictionary), the OED records its figurative use "The condition of mental, spiritual, or moral ill health (of an individual, of society or some section of it, or of the human race); any such condition that calls for a remedy" from 1385 onwards.

So, no, a *malady* doesn't necessarily have to be medical.

But even if its main use is medical, there is not necessarily anything wrong with including words that are not logically necessary. There are many different reasons why speakers and writers might do so. We'd nee to see more of the article to know why the writer chose to do so in this case.

Comment: One possible reason in the cited context is simply the stylistic choice to introduce an element of ***alliteration***

Comment: @FumbleFingers: indeed. I was going to mention prosody as a possibility.